# int depth UNUSED_PARAM

Tags: c, busybox

```
static FAST_FUNC int fileAction(const char *pathname,
    struct stat *sb UNUSED_PARAM,
    void *modname_to_match,
    int depth UNUSED_PARAM){...}
```

what does "int depth UNUSED_PARAM" mean ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `include/platform.h` in Busybox-1.18.3:

```
#define UNUSED_PARAM __attribute__ ((__unused__))
```

And from the [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.1/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html):

> `unused`
>   This attribute, attached to a variable, means that the variable is meant to be possibly
>   unused. GCC will not produce a warning for this variable.

So, it is just a way to tell both the human programmers and the compiler that the variable is not necessarily used. Otherwise, the compiler may warn you about an unused variable.

Presumably, `fileAction` requires the `depth` parameter to be compatible with a function pointer type or other API constraints but `fileAction` doesn't actually use the parameter.

Comment: +10 for going to the trouble of identifying this code and thereby giving the precise answer.

Comment: @Jim Balter: Thanks. The question did have the "busybox" tag and it was pretty clear what the macro was for; just took a quick download and some find/grep wrangling to verify it. Cheers.

Comment: @mu Yeah, I saw the tag after I posted that, and of course a knowledgeable and experienced C programmer knows about the gcc attribute and that the macro most likely evaluates to it, but still the effort to go find the header file is beyond the ordinary.

Comment: Note that a compiler that warns you about unused *function arguments* as opposed to just non-argument local variables is bogus. The arguments are determined by the signature the function must conform to, which could be a constraint of a callback API, function pointer type, etc.

Comment: @R..: Perhaps, but I'll take an overly strict and whiny compiler over an overly loose one in a heart beat.